# How to return the output of stored procedure into a variable in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

I want to execute a stored procedure in SQL Server and assign the output to a variable (it returns a single value) ?

Comment: What does your stored procedure return? A single value? A result set?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

That depends on the nature of the information you want to return.

If it is a single integer value, you can use the `return` statement

```
 create proc myproc
 as 
 begin
     return 1
 end
 go
 declare @i int
 exec @i = myproc
```

If you have a non integer value, or a number of scalar values, you can use output parameters

```
create proc myproc
  @a int output,
  @b varchar(50) output
as
begin
  select @a = 1, @b='hello'
end
go
declare @i int, @j varchar(50)
exec myproc @i output, @j output
```

If you want to return a dataset, you can use `insert exec`

```
create proc myproc
as 
begin
     select name from sysobjects
end
go

declare @t table (name varchar(100))
insert @t (name)
exec myproc
```

You can even return a cursor but that's just horrid so I shan't give an example :)

Comment: For integers, you should still use output parameters. Reserve return value for what they are designed: status. Good programmers separate concepts and write solid code. What happens if your stored procedure that returns an integer happens to fail?

Comment: i did observed an anomoly that when i return a decimal its decimal places are zero's but when i change it to select it returns decimal places correctly.

Comment: @DRAM `return` returns a single **integer** value

Comment: the last return example, was very useful, i was able to return a dataset, and assign field data to a couple of variables>>using [ select @variable= name from @t]

Comment: what about if you have `SELECT @Id` and `@Id` is not an output variable ?

Comment: @Muflix, in that case, use the INSERT/EXEC example.

Comment: For SQL Server 2008 R2: If `myproc` has multiple statements, then `@i` will always be zero `0` when calling `exec @i = myproc` unless the first statement in the stored procedure is `set nocount on`.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `return` statement inside a stored procedure to return an integer status code (and only of integer type). By convention a return value of zero is used for success.

If no `return` is explicitly set, then the stored procedure returns zero.

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE GetImmediateManager
      @employeeID INT,
      @managerID INT OUTPUT
   AS
   BEGIN
     SELECT @managerID = ManagerID 
     FROM HumanResources.Employee 
     WHERE EmployeeID = @employeeID

     if @@rowcount = 0 -- manager not found?
       return 1;
   END
```

And you call it this way:

```
DECLARE @return_status int;
DECLARE @managerID int;

EXEC @return_status = GetImmediateManager 2, @managerID output;
if @return_status = 1
  print N'Immediate manager not found!';
else 
  print N'ManagerID is ' + @managerID;
go
```

You should use the return value for status codes only. To return data, you should use output parameters.

If you want to return a dataset, then use an output parameter of type `cursor`.

[more on RETURN statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

Use this code, Working properly

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_delete_item]
@ItemId int = 0
@status bit OUT

AS
Begin
 DECLARE @cnt int;
 DECLARE @status int =0;
 SET NOCOUNT OFF
 SELECT @cnt =COUNT(Id) from ItemTransaction where ItemId = @ItemId
 if(@cnt = 1)
   Begin
     return @status;
   End
 else
  Begin
   SET @status =1;
    return @status;
 End
END
```

**Execute SP**

```
DECLARE @statuss bit;
EXECUTE  [dbo].[sp_delete_item] 6, @statuss output;
PRINT @statuss;
```

Answer (score 2):

With the Return statement from the proc, I needed to assign the temp variable and pass it to another stored procedure.  The value was getting assigned fine but when passing it as a parameter, it lost the value.  I had to create a temp table and set the variable from the table (SQL 2008)

```
From this: 
declare @anID int
exec @anID = dbo.StoredProc_Fetch @ID, @anotherID, @finalID
exec dbo.ADifferentStoredProc @anID (no value here)

To this:
declare @t table(id int) 
declare @anID int
insert into @t exec dbo.StoredProc_Fetch @ID, @anotherID, @finalID
set @anID= (select Top 1 * from @t)
```