# Procedure calling other procedure in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this T-SQL procedure in SQL Server 2008 :

```
create procedure rolledback  as 
begin
  set nocount on ;

  declare @min int
  declare @max int
  declare @I INT

  IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMDB..#TempTable') IS NOT  NULL
    begin 
      drop table #TempTable
  end 
  create table #TempTable
       ( TempOrderNumber int  )
  SELECT @min = ( SELECT MIN (numero)                           
               from controlanum  with (nolock))

  SELECT @max =  ( SELECT Max (numero)                           
               from controlanum  with (nolock))   

select @I = @min 

while @I <= @max
    begin
          insert into #TempTable 
          select  @I 
          select  @I = @I + 1               
    end            
  select tempordernumber from #TempTable               
  left join controlanum O  with (nolock) 
  on TempOrderNumber = o.numero  where o.numero is null                              
 end
```

This works perfect with the view controlanum, but I need to choose the date interval

I have written two other procedures to filter this period

```
 create proc maxiN (@emp int, @mes int, @ano int)
 as
     select Max (numero)
     from ctrc 
     WHERE (EMITENTE = @emp) 
     AND (MONTH(EMISSAODATA) = @mes) AND (YEAR(EMISSAODATA) = @ano)

 create proc Minix (@emp int, @mes int, @ano int)
 as
    select Min (numero)
    from ctrc 
    WHERE (EMITENTE = @emp) 
    AND (MONTH(EMISSAODATA) = @mes) AND (YEAR(EMISSAODATA) = @ano)
```

I have  insert these procedures in the `rolledback` procedure , but something is wrong now rolledback2 returns 0 is like the procedures for max and min returns anything.

```
create procedure rolledback2 ( @emp int, @mes int, @ano int) as 
begin
    set nocount on ;

    declare @min int
    declare @max int
    declare @I INT


     IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMDB..#TempTable') IS NOT  NULL
        begin 
             drop table #TempTable
        end 
     create table #TempTable
       ( TempOrderNumber int  )
     exec @min = min2 @emp,@mes ,@ano

     exec @min = min2 @emp,@mes ,@ano   

   select @I = @min 

  while @I <= @max
        begin
             insert into #TempTable 
             select  @I 
             select  @I = @I + 1               
        end            
  select tempordernumber from #TempTable               
  left join controlanum O  with (nolock) 
   on TempOrderNumber = o.numero  where o.numero is null                              
  end
```

and with function do not return anything

```
  declare @min int
  select @min = fmin 504,2,2013
```

only works this way

fmin 504,2,2013

Thanks any orientation

Alejandro

Answer (score 3):

You can't `SELECT` data like that from a stored procedure - you'd have to put the resultant data into a (temp) table to get at it.  You may want to create those as functions instead, since they are just `SELECT`ing data, and then you can use them inline.

```
CREATE FUNCTION maxiN
(
    @emp int,
    @mes int,
    @ano int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT;

    select @Result = Max (numero)
                     from ctrc
                     WHERE (EMITENTE = @emp) 
                           AND (MONTH(EMISSAODATA) = @mes)
                           AND (YEAR(EMISSAODATA) = @ano);

    RETURN @Result;
END
GO
```

Then use them in your stored proc:

```
SELECT @max = maxIN(@emp, @mes ,@ano)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like zimdanen says, a function is perfect for this. However, if you really want to use a stored procedure, you can use the output parameter and set it in your Minix and maxiN stored procedures.Then, reference them when you exec the proc.

```
create proc myproc
  @b varchar(50) output
as
begin
  select  @b='hello'
end
go
declare  @j varchar(50)
exec myproc @j output
```

See for more info : [How to return the output of stored procedure into a variable in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965269/how-to-return-the-output-of-stored-procedure-into-a-variable-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.rolledback
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
          @max INT
        , @min INT

    DECLARE @TempTable TABLE 
    (
        TempOrderNumber INT
    )

    SELECT 
          @min = MIN(numero) 
        , @max =  MAX(numero)  
    FROM dbo.controlanum WITH(NOLOCK)

    INSERT INTO @TempTable (TempOrderNumber)
    SELECT d.num
    FROM (
        SELECT num = @min + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sv.number) 
        FROM [master].dbo.spt_values sv
        LEFT JOIN [master].dbo.spt_values sv2 ON @max > 2048 AND sv2.[type] = 'P' AND sv2.number < 5
        WHERE sv.[type] = 'P'
    ) d
    WHERE num <= @max 

    SELECT TempOrderNumber 
    FROM @TempTable               
    LEFT JOIN controlanum o WITH(NOLOCK) ON TempOrderNumber = o.numero  
    WHERE o.numero IS NULL  

END
```

And answer on your question:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.maxiN 
(
      @emp INT
    , @mes INT
    , @ano INT
)
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @result INT

    SELECT @result = MAX(numero)
    FROM ctrc 
    WHERE EMITENTE = @emp 
        AND MONTH(EMISSAODATA) = @mes 
        AND YEAR(EMISSAODATA) = @ano

    RETURN @result

END
```

Exec:

```
EXEC @max = dbo.maxiN @emp2, @mes2, @ano2
```