# SQL Code not returning any values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure that is being called in `C#`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetJobStatusSummary] @FiscalYear int,
@JobIDList varchar(max)
AS
  SELECT
    SUM(CASE StatusID
      WHEN 5 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END) AS Completed,
    SUM(CASE StatusID
      WHEN 5 THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END) AS Incomplete
  FROM Review
  WHERE FiscalYear = @FiscalYear
  AND JobID + '|' + Position IN (SELECT
    Argument
  FROM dbo.CreateInClause(@JobIDList))
  GROUP BY FiscalYear
```

When I pass in the following (this was taken from SQL Server Management Studio):

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[GetJobStatusSummary] @FiscalYear = 2015,
                                                 @JobDList = N'00304730,00334573,00635385,'

SELECT
  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

I'm not getting anything back for Completed or Incomplete, just a return value of 0. I've verified there is in fact data in the database pertaining to these Job ID's. I'm not that skilled at SQL, as I've sort of inherited this project. The stored procedure hasn't changed, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any ideas?

Edit: 
Sample of data from the table, is this useful? The ID's I'm using to test are not represented here, but this is an example of the data in there

```
JobID   StatusID  FiscalYear    CreatedDT   LastUpdatedDT
14999       5       2011    55:15.4 12:15.3
163511      2       2011    08:20.6 12:15.3
```

Comment: Can you also post some of the data in the table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the output of stored procedure into a variable in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965269/how-to-return-the-output-of-stored-procedure-into-a-variable-in-sql-server)

Comment: take the select statement from the procedure and execute it seperately by giving the values you passed and check is it returning values for complete and incomplete

Comment: @JesseEarley post the sample content of the table

Comment: Can you post the result for `SELECT Argument                                        FROM dbo.CreateInClause('00304730,00334573,00635385,')` and a few sample entires from `select JobID + '|' + Position from Review`

Comment: When you want to get data out of a procedure the correct way to do that is with OUTPUT parameters, NOT the return value from the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM( CASE StatusID WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Completed  ,
    SUM( CASE StatusID WHEN 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS Incomplete,
    FiscalYear
FROM    Review
WHERE   FiscalYear = @FiscalYear AND 
        JobID + '|' + Position IN ( SELECT Argument FROM dbo.CreateInClause( @JobIDList ) )
GROUP BY FiscalYear
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work for me, it's not returning any values.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

is going to return 0 if the procedure execute correctly. The @return_value is that for. So you don't need to use SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value at the end of the call.

try executting you're query along with the parameters so you can determine if it is good.

And try again just:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @FiscalYear int
DECLARE @JobDList VARCHAR(MAX)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetJobStatusSummary]
        @FiscalYear = 2015,
        @JobDList = N'00304730,00334573,00635385,'
```

Comment: I got "Completed" and "Incomplete", neither of which has any values. I'm beyond my realm of knowledge now, as I'm just working maintenance on this application. However, with that said, the stored procedure hasn't changed, so I'm not sure why it would quit returning a value. Looking at the stored procedure code I provided, does it look as though the parameters that are being passed in are in the correct format?

Comment: try posting the result of:    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE StatusID WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed,
        SUM(CASE StatusID WHEN 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Incomplete
    FROM    
        Review
    WHERE   
        FiscalYear = 2015
        AND JobID + '|' + Position IN (SELECT Argument 
        FROM dbo.CreateInClause('00304730,00334573,00635385,'))
    GROUP BY 
        FiscalYear

Comment: I got the same thing as my previous comment, just the Completed and Incomplete output with no value.

Comment: So, the answer is that you're stored procedure is ok. The query is not founding any data with that filters.

Comment: The dbo.CreateInClause is another stored procedure? what it does?

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'm not sure why that would be. This application is currently in production and working ok...I'm working in our staging environment and everything was copied down from there. The only difference I know of is that the staging database is running on the newest version of SQL Server, and the production environment is on an older version.

Comment: If is the staging enviroment maybe you don´t have all the data you need in those tables. Could you ask the dba to restore a backup on this enviroment?

Comment: i should have all of the data, at least as of yesterday, as I had the dba do just that. It's an exact copy of production as of yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by execute the two queries to see if there is any data in the tables:

```
SELECT StatusID FROM Review WHERE FiscalYear = 2015;
```

And when there are results, check what the output of 'JobID + '|' + Position' is.

```
SELECT StatusID, JobID + '|' + Position FROM Review WHERE FiscalYear = 2015;
```

Maybe you can see that the output is not in the list which comes out of: 
SELECT Argument FROM dbo.CreateInClause( @JobIDList )

Comment: well, running both of those independently returned results :)

Comment: And what about in one statement? Then you know your input is not found.

Comment: running: SELECT StatusID, StatusID, EmployeeID + '|' + Position FROM Review WHERE FiscalYear = 2015;

also returns values

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.
As I said, the SQL (unless it's just selecting something) is above my head, but since I know the SQL didn't change, it looks like the C# did.

I have this line of code in my C#

```
var jobs= from d in jobData select d.JobID;
```

In the SQL it was also looking for position to be there, with the "|", which it was not. I changed that line to:

```
var jobs= from d in jobData select d.JobID;+ "|" + d.Position
```

I apologize if I posted this in the wrong forum.