# Stored procedure within a stored procedure only gets executed when the parent stored procedure is executed the second time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

```
create procedure  spGoti
    @WeekNumber nvarchar(255)
as
begin

    execute spPointsUpdate @WeekNumber

    execute spGivebadges @WeekNumber

    execute spLevelField @WeekNumber
    execute spAddNewWeekDataToTotalOfEmployeeTable @WeekNumber

    execute spTop15Overall
    execute spWeeklytop15 @WeekNumber

end
```

in the above code I have written stored procedures within stored procedures.
I have a peculiar problem here. The second stored procedure (`spGivebadges @WeekNumber`) uses the output of previous stored procedure (`spPointsUpdate @WeekNumber`).

The problem is if I execute the parent stored procedure i.e `spGoti`, then the second stored procedure `spGivebadges @WeekNumber` does not get executed . But when I run `spGoti` the second time, then the second stored procedure gets executed without any problem.

All the other stored procedures within the parent gets executed the first time itself, though some are using output of another.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe the table that you use in the 2nd sproc is still locked (or not committed). Try adding COMMIT; to the end of the execution of the 1st sproc (or end of the execution of the table that you use in the 2nd sproc). Hope this help.

Comment: I think if your SP  spGivebadges using the values return from spPointsUpdate then it is also calling from 'spGivebadges ' if so then please try it by removing the first line --execute spPointsUpdate . If not so then please call that SP inside another and go on similar way and try.

Comment: You wrote that `spGivebadges ` uses output of `spPointsUpdate `, it is within some temporary tables? As for now this question reminds me [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You are almost certainly going to need the definition of `spPointsUpdate` and `spGivebadges`. While you are adding the definitions to the question, you may wish to tidy up the formatting, the mix of caps and bold makes it hard to read, and also makes it look like you are shouting.

Comment: The output of spPointsUpdate is not within any temporary table @gofr1

Comment: @PriyaSingh well... where is it then?

Comment: This will solve your issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965269/how-to-return-the-output-of-stored-procedure-into-a-variable-in-sql-server

Comment: Does spPointsUpdate take longer to execute if you run it individually ?