# How to set the result of a stored procedure to a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC usp123 @F1 = 1, @F2 = 'A', @F3 = 5

DECLARE @Result int

SET @Result = (EXEC usp123 @F1 = 1, @F2 = 'A', @F3 = 5)
```

How do I assign a variable to the output of this stored procedure as the above syntax does not work ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the output of stored procedure into a variable in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965269/how-to-return-the-output-of-stored-procedure-into-a-variable-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

The last line should be

```
Declare @Result Int
EXEC @Result = usp123 @F1 = 1, @F2 = 'A', @F3 = 5
```

Comment: I have found the answer. You would have to put the OUTPUT keyword in the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Check this... your answer is in the last sentence.



DECLARE @IntVariable int;  
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @max_title varchar(30);  

SET @IntVariable = 197;  
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @max_titleOUT = max(JobTitle)   
   FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee  
   WHERE BusinessEntityID = @level';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@level tinyint, @max_titleOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT';  

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @level = @IntVariable, 
@max_titleOUT=@max_title OUTPUT;  
SELECT @max_title;
```