# Use return type stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, return, scalar

I created a stored procedure which returns a particular value, but I am not able to store the return value of my stored procedure in a scalar variable.

I am getting this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '2014-03-01'.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_generatePaymentID
    @date nvarchar(50),
    @trainer nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result as int
    DECLARE @paymentid as int

    SET @date='2017-08-22'
    SET @result = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM finalinstructoreexpense 
                   WHERE date = @date AND trainer = '@trainer')

    IF (@result = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @paymentid = (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @date, 103), '-', ''))
        SELECT CAST(@paymentid AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '001'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @paymentid = (SELECT TOP 1 paymentid 
                          FROM finalinstructoreexpense 
                          WHERE date = @date AND trainer = '@trainer' 
                          ORDER BY paymentid DESC)
        SELECT @paymentid + 1
    END

    RETURN @paymentid
END
```

When I execute the procedure

```
exec SP_generatePaymentID '2014-03-01','Benzir Pinjari'
```

this is showing me record in my result window (`20170822001`).

This is my **result**

but when I try to store the value in my scalar variable like this

```
declare @paymentID as int

set @paymentID = SP_generatePaymentID '2014-03-01','Benzir Pinjari'
select @paymentID
```

It is throwing an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '2014-03-01'.

What is wrong here? What do I need to do to store the output value in my scalar variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the output of stored procedure into a variable in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965269/how-to-return-the-output-of-stored-procedure-into-a-variable-in-sql-server)

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Why do you pass in a variable named date that is actually a varchar and then set it to a hard coded value? Dates should be dates, not strings. And why bother with a parameter here? I would suggest adding some formatting to your code as this is painful to look at. You also have your parameters @trainer as string literals, not parameters.

Comment: @SeanLange this is just a test example for stackoverflow i have a bigger procedure

Comment: So you posted an error message and expect somebody to decipher some code that didn't generate that message and tell where in your real code the issue it. How do you expect anybody to do that. The pseudocode you posted here is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with the code you posted. The first issue is that you have defined @paymentid as an int but you are putting too many characters in the string for it to fit in an int.

The default value you have is 20170822001 but that is not a valid integer value. You are going to have to use varchar(11) or longer.

Your entire procedure could be greatly simplified so something along these lines. Since you can't use an int you are going to have to use an OUTPUT parameter instead of a return value. I don't think is totally correct but you stated this code is only kind of sort of like what your real code is anyway.

```
declare @date nvarchar(50),
@trainer nvarchar(50)
declare @result as int
declare @paymentid as varchar(20)
set @date='2017-08-22'

--set the default value first
set @paymentid = convert(varchar(100), REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @date, 103), '-', '')) +'001'

select @paymentid

--if there are no rows returned from this query the value of @paymentid will not be changed
select @paymentid = convert(varchar(10), MAX(paymentid) + 1)
from finalinstructoreexpense 
where date = @date 
    and trainer = @trainer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @paymentID as int
set @paymentID =SP_generatePaymentID '2014-03-01','Benzir Pinjari'
select @paymentID

please use "Exec" instead of set

declare @paymentID as int
EXEC  @paymentID = SP_generatePaymentID '2014-03-01','Benzir Pinjari'
select @paymentID
```