# SQL - Use different Select Statements based on column value

Tags: sql

For instance,

```
Select field1

From table1

when table1.field1 = 'S'

     then (select field1,2,3,4,5,6,.....
           form table1,2,3,4,5,6,....(with joins))

when table1.field1 = 'O'

     then (select field1,2,3,4,5,6,.....
           from table1,2,3,4,5,6,.....(with join))
```

Comment: share sample data and expected output sample

Comment: Please also add the tag for the database provider you have (for e.x. Oracle, Postgres etcl), that may enable targeted answers.

Comment: Using Microsoft Sql Sever. -- Based on 'S' and 'O' will determine which joining sequences are used. The output data will/should be identical. However, since we are using a business software it tags orders differently. S - Scheduled Release and O - Order, I will be getting the same information from both clauses, but the flow of how to join and where to push information to is different based on the letters.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you need. One possible solution is to create a view with hardcoded where clauses on it. This is the idea:

```
CREATE VIEW ConditionalSelect AS
SELECT ...fields...
FROM ...tables...
JOIN ...joins...
WHERE table1.field1 = 'S'
AND ....

UNION

SELECT ...fields...
FROM ...tables...
JOIN ...joins...
WHERE table1.field1 = 'O'
AND ....
```

Then you can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ConditionalSelect
WHERE field1 = 'S'
```

**NOTE**: Both `SELECT` MUST have the same columns, columns types and column names, either the `VIEW` won't compile.

Comment: I think this is close to what I need. The above code I started will be created in a view and that view will be joined to a built in SQL statement based on a production order number.

Comment: Please mark any answer as correct if you consider so.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Field1 VARCHAR(10) =
(
    SELECT Field1
    FROM table1
);

IF(@Field1 = 'S')
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON t2.col1 = t1.col1 
END
ELSE IF (@Field1 = 'O')
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON t2.col1 = t1.col1 
END
```

Saves you from creating a view

Comment: After tinkering around with this, this DOES return what I'm looking for but I need to be able to get the same data this returns as a view, so that i can join that view to the prebuilt sql function in our business software. Is it possible to save this as a stored procedure and pass along a Production order number to it from a view and return the store procedure's value?

Comment: Yeah you could do that. See the following question as an example of how to return data from an SP in SQL.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965269/how-to-return-the-output-of-stored-procedure-into-a-variable-in-sql-server